# Redefining variables in a \foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to plot some recursively defined sequence with tikz and am encountering some behavior I can't understand, here is my code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\f}{1}
\foreach\i in {1,...,10} {
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ff}{\i*\f}
  \draw (0,\i) node {\ff};
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\f}{\ff}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would have expected this to print the sequence of the factorials of the first ten integers (going down) but what I get is 10,9,...,1. What is happening ? How can I handle such recursively defined functions in Tikz ?

Comment: May be you can use `evaluate` and `count` keys from `\foreach \i [count=..,evaluate=..] ..`.

Comment: Could you expand, I'm not familiar with evaluate and count ?

Comment: Add `\global\let\f=\f` at the end of your loop. Another issue:  $7!$ is the maximum value computable by TeX (TeX maximum value is 16383.99998).

Comment: Well the factorial was just for the example. This seems to have solved my problem. You can make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code in the `foreach` loop is in a TeX group, so all definitions are local to this group. Add `\global\let\f=\ff` at the end of your loop. As suggested by egreg in his comment, a global macro with a short name is very likely to break something. You may rename `\f` with a long name.

Another issue: `$7!$` is the maximum factorial computable by TeX (TeX maximum value is 16383.99998).

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\myglobalfactorial}{1}
  \foreach\i in {1,...,7} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ff}{\i*\myglobalfactorial}
    \draw (0,\i) node {\ff};
    %\pgfmathsetmacro{\myglobalfactorial}{\ff}
    \global\let\myglobalfactorial=\ff
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Other solution using `evaluate` and `remember` keys (the remembered variable is always global so choose a long name):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ff using \i*\myglobalfactorial,
               remember=\ff as \myglobalfactorial (initially 1)] in {1,...,7} {
    \draw (0,\i) node {\ff};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is `\pgfmathsetmacro{\f}{\ff}` supposed to do? Why not simply `\global\let\f=\ff`? By the way, the first line should be `\pgfmathsetmacro{\temp}{<expression>}\global\let\f=\temp`. This prevents save stack buildup, that happens when there are global and local assignments to the same variable (in this case the macro `\f`). Finally, setting globally a macro with a short name is very likely to break something.

Comment: @egreg I keep the lines and the macro names from MWE provided by OP. You are right: it's dangerous and inefficient.

Comment: @egreg I edited my answer...