# The tikz variable resets before the loop finishes

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, arithmetic

In tikz, I define a variable outside `\foreach` loop, and use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` command to increase it inside the loop.

Below is my MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz,tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{1};
    \foreach \i in {1,4,7}
    {

        \node at (\i,1.4) {\j};
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\j+1};
        \node at (\i+1.5,1.4) {\j};
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\j+1};
        \node at (\i,0) {\j};
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\j+1};
        \node at (\i+1.5,0) {\j};
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Instead of increasing the value of `\j` up to 12, it resets back to 1 after only one iteration of the loop. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know what is the problem but you can resolve it by adding `\xdef\j{\j}` in last line inside loop.

Comment: See [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459361) for more information

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222281/201158 for the reason why you failed

Comment: @ZhiyuanLck Yup, every definition is local to loops. I keep forgetting this!